# Return uniqueidentifier in MSSQL Stored Procedures using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures, uniqueidentifier

I have a stored procedure and I whant to return an uniqueidentifier. So I declared an uniqueidentifier as OUTPUT. But then I "dragd and dropped" it do my LINQ to SQL DataClass and it would not recognize my returntype. It only recognized int or my linq classes.

How should I return the uniqueidentifier so I can use it with LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an explanation of [how to return a uniqueidentifier](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/micham/archive/2008/12/12/how-to-return-uniqueidentifier-initialized-with-newsequentialid-function-to-the-net-client.aspx). It contains some examples on returning the Guid.

> Solution:
>
> For .Net client using System.Data.SQLClient
>
> The solution is to use the OUTPUT clause with the insert statement so
>   that the generated primary key can be extracted with the
>   ExecuteScalar() method of the SqlCommand object.
>
> For. Net client using LINQ to SQL
>
> Because the SQL Server generates the primary key in this scenario, the
>   LINQ to SQL will only work correctly if the Column attribute with
>   IsDbGenerated=true property is applied to entity property that
>   corresponds to the underlying primary key column.

There is also a question on SO regarding this issue:

[LINQ to SQL entity column name attribute ignored with guid primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067274/linq-to-sql-entity-column-name-attribute-ignored-with-guid-primary-key)